# Android Intent getExtras() causes Avast Alarm

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm trying to call an Activity and pass two values to it, a string and a integer.

I'm using the Android SDK with eclipse via USB debugging for testing. The thing is, when I launch the app on my device I suddenly get a warning from my Avast app (something about my app being an unwanted program - android:Agent-ACH [PUP]). I tested different devices, it's the same everywhere

This is the code to call the activity:

```
Intent ch = new Intent(context, ActivityChaos.class);
ch.putExtra("cards", Data.getNextCardsString(1, false));
ch.putExtra("ID", ID);
context.startActivityForResult(ch, ID);
```

And this is from the called activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chaos);

    Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
    String s = extra.getString("cards");
    // int ID = extra.getInt("ID");
    ...
}
```

The last line extra.getInt("ID") is the one that causes the alarm, once its commented out there is no problem.

What am I doing wrong? 
Is this just a false alarm or what's going on?
It's such a basic thing...

Comment: Just rename the extra. Any answer to your question would require us to make assumptions about what avast was or wasn't thinking.

Comment: I renamed the int extra to "cardid" but I still get an alarm...

Comment: Change the name of both extras (suggestion: Use a `static final String` and reference that from both spots, so you don't need to change it more than once), and then also swap the order of how you read them out. Somehow, your app matches the signature of a known trojan, and avast is so poorly written that a common operation, such as yours, sets of their false alarm.

Answer (score 0):

On the method context.startActivityForResult(ch, ID): if ID is >= 0, this code will be returned in onActivityResult() when the activity exits.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
    String s = extra.getString("cards");
    int ID = extra.getInt("ID");
}
```

From: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: Tried that too, no change. The weird thing is, the code isn't even "active" at the time of the alert (during the launch of the app)