# Avast detects Android:SmsCharger-B[Trj] in my Android application

Tags: android, android-permissions

Several users are reporting this Avast problem:

[image: Avast false alarm]

I'm only requesting this permissions in my application:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

And if you open application details everything looks good:

[image]

From this is clear that nothing in my application is related to SMS. I'm not using any services for ads or something that can refer to SMS in any context. I asked users to report this as false alarm, I also wrote to Avast support to report the obvious false alarm but nothing changed so far.

Has anyone managed to solve problem like this?

Comment: Are you using any third-party libraries?

Comment: appcompat-v7, apache.commons:commons-io, universal-image-loader, bugsense

Comment: It's conceivable that your copy of one of those has the malware injected in it, or that you are getting it from someplace else (e.g., ad network).

Comment: Can I somehow scan the libraries and figure it out? Btw, application is ad free and I'm pretty sure that libraries also does not have any ad implementation.

Comment: I don't know whether you got that screenshot because you have Avast and can reproduce the message, or if you got that from a user. If you have Avast and can get it to complain, start tinkering with your app, removing libraries and such, to see if you can make the message go away.

Comment: Yes the screenshot is from user reporting the issue. Will try now with Avast. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you scan the APK with your regular anti-virus directly on your computer?  If you can pick up the malware there, I would then exclude libraries from your app one at a time and see when it goes away.  If you can't do that, just redownload new copies of the libraries and update them all.

Comment: I made scan with https://www.metascan-online.com and none of all 40 services find malware in the file. Avast is not on the list :)

Answer (score 0):

I only can assume. But! Check out a comment to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21528542/android-intent-getextras-causes-avast-alarm):

> Change the name of both extras (suggestion: Use a static final String and reference that from both spots, so you don't need to change it more than once), and then also swap the order of how you read them out. Somehow, your app matches the signature of a known trojan, and avast is so poorly written that a common operation, such as yours, sets of their false alarm.

It seems that Avast analysing not only permissions, but  other stuff. For example, name and order of your parameters. I'm having the same issue with Avast now.